# Strange 1px offset in MSIE for :after and :before

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a tag system with 'negative border radius' (I lack a better description).

I use `:after` and `:before` to create some faux border the 'bends outside'. It worked well, but there is some strange behaviour in MSIE. Normally I have `top:5px` on the `:after` and `:before`, but in IE I have to add an extra pixel (results in `top: 6px`) (See in IE8: the horizontal lines to the left and right should not be visible)

What could that be?

http://jsfiddle.net/rhGZw/3/

```html
<div class="test"><div>foo</div></div>
```

---

```css
body {
    background: gold;
    margin: 10px;
}
.test {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.test > div {
    background: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius : 5px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.test:before {
    content: '';
    width: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    background: none;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width:5px;
    border-right-width:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: -1;
}

.test:after {
    content: '';
    width: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    background: none;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width:5px;
    border-left-width:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: -1;
}

​
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm on a mac right now, so I can't test this on IE, but have you tried adding border box to fix the [box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)? Try adding `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;` to see if it works alright.

Comment: Your fiddle looks different in latest Firefox, Opera and Webkit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the error by myself. It was the vertical-align:middle with the :after and :before which caused the 1px offset

Answer (score 0):

The white borders are visible in Firefox and Opera too, not just IE. However, they blend into the border-radius.

It's easy to see at http://jsfiddle.net/CrxQG/ and http://jsfiddle.net/CrxQG/1/ with black border color and border-radius removed, respectively.

Comment: It's the intended behavior. But, when you look at IE9 the boder blend is offset 1px to the top.